# How to give path for log writing on amazon s3 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for hosting my java webite.
Now the problem i am facing is that i am not able to see my log file(Log4J logs)
So i want to use amazon s3 server for storing log
so can somebody tell me the process or way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Beanstalk FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/#store-in-s3) states that it does send log files to S3. 
[This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161069/rotating-s3-logging-using-log4j-with-elastic-beanstalk) and this [blog post referenced](http://www.lustforge.com/2012/07/15/logrotate-apache-logs-to-amazon-s3/)  (taken from the other SO question) have details on log4j and beanstalk