# Log4j appenders for logging into S3

Tags: java, logging, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I would like to save the logs while creating, updating, terminating an Ec2 instance into an external storage like S3. if it is possible what is the protocol? In the case of Auto_Scaling how we can track the instances? how to find which machine is created, in which region and all? can we use synchronized / Asynchronized Log4j Appenders for this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161069/rotating-s3-logging-using-log4j-with-elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this? S3Appender is a log4net appender that stores log events in either a MemoryStream or FileStream and sends them to S3 based on time intervals and size thresholds.
http://s3appender.codeplex.com/

Comment: Is that log4net appender compatible with log4j?

Comment: Well, log4net and log4j are nearly identical but it would have to be rewritten in Java. So to answer your question, @Danger, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this [S3Appender project](http://www.therealvan.com/s3loggerappender.html), but have not had a chance to try it yet.