# Reducing log rotation frequency for AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, log4j, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a java app running on elastic beanstalk, with the log rotation to S3 set up and working fine. However, I find that my catalina.out log file only exists for up to 15 minutes before rolling to a new file, which makes debugging problems on the same day more tedious (get gz from s3 and unzip, instead of just ssh-ing and reading the log file).

Is there any way to configure this through tomcat/log4j or the elastic-beanstalk console? I believe it's an AWS thing, because we had the same app deployed on Dotcloud and it kept a single log file per day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Today, not really. The only thing that you can do is modify the file /etc/logrotate.conf.elasticbeanstalk in the EC2 instance where your app is running.

Change the size of the log and that should put more log info in one file:

```
/var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out /var/log/tomcat6/monitor_catalina.log /var/log/tomcat6/tail_catalina.log {
    size 20M <-- change to the file size that you want
    missingok
    rotate 2
    compress
    notifempty
    copytruncate
    dateext
    dateformat -%s
    lastaction
        /bin/chown tomcat:elasticbeanstalk /var/log/tomcat6/*gz; /bin/chmod 664 /var/log/tomcat6/*gz
    endscript
}
```

There's another post that has more info here:

[Rotating S3 Logging using log4j with Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161069/rotating-s3-logging-using-log4j-with-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: where this file exist on `windows instance` ?

Comment: @max this applies only to Linux

Answer (score 3):

Even though this question is old and resolved, I hope the following helps more people like me who struggled with the whole concept.

### How log rotation *actually* works

I believe an explanation on how log rotation actually works might be more helpful, as the technical details will surely change over time and differ across platforms (in my examples I use php).

1. Elastic Beanstalk log rotations are done through `logrotate` and have configuration files inside the `/etc` directory in the form of `logrotate.elasticbeanstalk.hourly/logrotate.elasticbeanstalk.<service name>.conf`. As you can tell from the path, **hourly** indicates that logs should be rotated hourly. Note that this file doesn't *actually* rotate the logs, it's just a set of `logrotate` log-specific options that get executed when the rotation is actually performed.
2. Rotation actually happen through `cron`, a service that allows you to schedule when to run certain scripts. In this case, if you check the `/etc/cron.hourly` directory you will see files like `cron.logrotate.elasticbeanstalk.<service name>.conf` (don't let the .conf extension fool you, it's really an executable, note the `#!bin/sh` at the top).  When `cron` executes this script, it will run `logrotate` for the specified `logrotate` conf file.
3. The file that actually dictates at what time `cron` runs hourly jobs is `/etc/cron.d/0hourly`. The file that dictates at what time it runs daily/weekly/monthly jobs is `/etc/anacrontab`. As a side note, I believe that all `logrotate` conf files inside the `/etc/logrotate.d` directory get executed daily, as specified in `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`.

### Your options

With this basic info, you should be able to understand how to change the frequency of rotation to your liking. For instance:

- If you just care about the interval and not the specific rotation time, you can simply move the rotation script to the appropriate `/etc/cron.<interval>` directory:

  ```
  mv /etc/cron.hourly/cron.logrotate.elasticbeanstalk.healthd.conf /etc/cron.daily/
  ```
- If you want more control, pull the script out of the cron directory so it stops getting executed at default intervals:

  ```
  mv /etc/cron.hourly/cron.logrotate.elasticbeanstalk.healthd.conf /etc/
  ```

  Then, create a custom `cron` job inside the `/etc/cron.d` directory, specifying when to run the script. Example:

  ```
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
  MAILTO=""
  HOME=/
  05 3 * * * root /etc/cron.logrotate.elasticbeanstalk.healthd.conf
  ```

  which will run once a day, every day at 3:05am.

  Note: if you decide to create your own script, make sure it has execute permission, otherwise `cron` won't be able to run it.

For me, modifying these files only worked as a [predeploy platform hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). However, if you're not changing the default AWS log rotations/cron jobs but just adding your own, you can safely do that in a config file inside `.ebextensions`.

Comment: Your comment is really valuable to me. I'm trying to understand what happens to all the log files in Beanstalk