# Customizing ec2 log rotation to S3 on elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, logrotate

I have an AWS elastic beanstalk environment with some amazon linux instances running a tomcat8 server. I have enabled log rotation from the beanstalk console and I can see the logs getting published to S3 every hour.

I would like to reduce the frequency of the rotation from 1 hour to maybe 12 hours (or something customizable that i can decide later - if customization is limited, i can fallback to daily). The only related pointers that I've found in the documentation is that the logrotate configuration is at `/etc/logrotate.elasticbeanstalk.hourly/` and that the cron job runs hourly as defined here `/etc/cron.hourly/`.

The default logrotate configuration for tomcat is set to rotate after size:10mb but the force flag in the cron task basically ignores this and ends up rotating the log file much sooner (I don't have a whole lot of traffic). Too many log files makes it very annoying to use for any sort of debugging later.

1. How can I go about changing the logrotate configuration and override the cron job? Is the recommended option to overwrite these config files via a script in `.ebextensions` folder?
2. When an instance is terminated (replaced by another one during rolling updates or any other reason) then does Elastic Beanstalk automatically back up the pending logs to S3 or do we lose them? What changes should I do or not do in above configuration so I can ensure that all logs are updated to S3?

Comment: Refer this question don't know if there is a change in this situation from AWS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187974/reducing-log-rotation-frequency-for-aws-ec2?rq=1

Comment: @error2007s - did see that earlier. am hoping there is a better supported solution by AWS now. bigger worry around customising this is that I'm not sure if beanstalk currently does a force upload of pending logs before terminating the instance - not doing this could mean too much log loss if i lower the rotation frequency.