# Easier way to access ElasticBeanstalk EC2 Log files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jersey, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am programming a Jersey service on Tomcat via EBS with LoadBalancer. I am finding getting the EC2's S3 catalina files very cumbersome. Currently I need to determine the EC2 instance(s) then work my way to each of the S3 locations, download the files, then I can diagnose.

The snapshot doesn't help due to the amount of requests that come in, it doesn't hold enough info and by the time I get the snapshot, it has "rolled" off the snapshot.

Two questions:

1) Is there an easier approach to logs files via AWS? (Increase time before rotation which I don't believe is supported as of now, scripts, etc)

2) Is there any software or scripts to access all the logs under load balancer? I am basically wanting to say "give me all logs for this EBS" and have it get all logs for that day under all servers for that load balancer (up or down)". The clincher is down. Problem becomes more complex when the load balancer takes down an instance right when the issue occurs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an immediate solution to your problem you can follow the approach suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11493922/161628) answer. Essentially you can modify the logrotate configuration to rotate for a bigger log size using [ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html).
Then snapshot logs should work for you.

Let me know if you need more clarifications on this approach.

Comment: How to set-up stuff on `Windows instances running IIS`?

Answer (score 1):

AWS has released [CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) just last week, which enables you to *to monitor and troubleshoot your systems and applications using your existing system, application, and custom log files*:

> You can send your existing system, application, and custom log files to CloudWatch Logs and monitor these logs in near real-time. [...] you can store your logs using highly durable, low-cost storage for later access.

See the introductory blog post [Store and Monitor OS & Application Log Files with Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-log-service/) for an illustrated walk through, which touches on using *Elastic Beanstalk and CloudWatch Logs* already - this is further detailed in [Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html).